# WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the requested channel

Tags: conda

I'm seeing strange errors from conda when I attempt to install a package.  Merely searching for packages results in strange warnings like the following.  What's going on?

```
(base) $ conda search libdvid-cpp
Fetching package metadata ....
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/flyem-forge

It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.

If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that the
channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
`noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
..
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge

It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.

If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that the
channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
`noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
.........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

 - [('libdvid-cpp',)]

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

 - https://conda.anaconda.org/flyem-forge/osx-64
 - https://conda.anaconda.org/flyem-forge/noarch
 - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
 - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
 - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Comment: We were probably both running into [this issue]( https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6646 ).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  In our case, we thought that flushing the DNS cache magically fixed the issue, but now I think that was an illusion.  Kale fixed the issue during lunch, and we tried the DNS "fix" just after lunch. :-/

Answer (score 4):

Conda is having trouble reading the remote package repositories.  Here are some things to try:

### Double-check your list of channels

Check in `~/.condarc` or `.../miniconda/.condarc`.  Or use the following command to see where your configuration files are:

```
conda config --show-sources
```

Make sure that all channel names are spelled correctly.

### Try refresh your token for `anaconda.org`

```
anaconda logout
anaconda login
```

(If you don't have the `anaconda` command installed, then this issue does not apply to you.)

### Try flushing your DNS cache:

On Mac:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

On Linux, your DNS entries might not be cached at all, but see here:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/how-to-flush-local-dns-cache-in-centos
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache